# How Can I Get Thread Priority From JMX?

Tags: java, jmx

My application needs to create a thread dump from a remote process using JMX so I have used this as a starting point:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm

It uses the java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean class to get the ThreadInfo.

However, the output of jstack includes the thread priority

```
"pool-5-thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009da0000 nid=0x1820 waiting on condition   [0x000000000c35e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
```

How can I get this using JMX?

Comment: You are aware that the priority does almost nothing, you should treat it as a hint at best and a comment at worst.

Comment: Certain Open Source thread dump analysers fail to parse the output if it isnt there. I have hardcoded prio=-1 for now but I would like to get the same as jstack if possible.

Comment: I suggest you fix the open source code so it doesn't have to have the priority.

Comment: Thanks. You aren't really helping to answer the question though.

Comment: That's why I am commenting, instead of typing in the answer block.  I am trying to tell you are heading down the wrong road.

Comment: By open source thread dump analyzers, you are referring to TDA - https://java.net/projects/tda?

Answer (score 0):

JStack attaches using the JVM debugger interface, not through JMX.  That's how it can get to the priority info.

The ThreadMXBean doesn't expose priority as far as I can see so you'd need to write your own JMX bean or change your client to connect as a debugger.

You can see how JStack works by looking in the source for OpenJDK:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/tools/jstack/JStack.java#JStack.runThreadDump%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String[]%29